# Objective C How do I make a timer that counts down from two minutes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, timer, nstimer

I searched around the internet for an answer but with no luck. I tried

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

twoMinTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; }

- (void)timer {
for (int totalSeconds = 120; totalSeconds > 0; totalSeconds--){

timerLabel.text = [self timeFormatted:totalSeconds];

if ( totalSeconds == 0 ) {

   [twoMinTimer invalidate];

   } } }
```

but it didn't work, the label went from 2.00 to 0.01 when I went to that view and then it just stopped.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated
- Philip

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using a one off for loop instead of simply decrementing the total amount of time.  Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    totalSeconds = 120;
    twoMinTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(timer)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timer {
    totalSeconds--;
    timerLabel.text = [self timeFormatted:totalSeconds];
    if ( totalSeconds == 0 ) {
        [twoMinTimer invalidate];
    } 
}
```

Declare `totalSeconds` as an int.

EDIT:  My absolute thanks for @JoshCaswell and @MichaelDorst for the suggestions and code formatting respectively.  NSTimer is in no way an accurate representation of time, and is definitely not accurate enough for a stopwatch or counter.  Instead, NSDate's `+dateSinceNow` would be a more accurate substitute, or even the progressively lower level `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` and  `mach_absolute_time()` are accurate to sub-milliseconds

Comment: Yes, I know, but the code still looks ugly as sin without a dedicated tab key on this thing.

Comment: BTW, actually on-topic: for a real-time "stopwatch", it's generally best to check the date rather than just decrementing a counter -- the display will always be correct even if the `NSTimer` is delayed.

Comment: You can't tab on a SO post anyways.

Comment: I have Xcode set to space-only, so don't worry ;).  And you're absolutely right.  Stick around, I'll be badly formatting another piece of code.

Comment: What @JoshCaswell said;  you never want to use a 1 second interval timer and then count the timer ticks to try and time anything with any need for accuracy.   Every tick will have some, potentially a lot, of slop and that slop will accumulate.    Either check the date as Josh said or use 2 timers; a one-shot for the interval desired and an update timer to tickle the display.